# How to sort array of NSMutableDictionary store in NSUserDefault?

Tags: swift, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an array of NSMutableDictionary saved with NSUserDefault , I want to sort the array based on "timestamp" key (the value is a String) in each NSMutableDictionary :
that the code I use to retrieve the array:

```
     if let chatsArray = NSUserDefaults().arrayForKey("myChatsList") as? [NSMutableDictionary]{
            print(chatsArray)
            //sort the array
            print(sortedArray)
     }
```

thats how my array look like:

```
[{
    eventBadge = 1;
    eventId = "-KWE39B6Dh7rDzaF-xy4";
    lastMessage = uyfgduihgvifudhviufhvdf;
    timestamp = 20;
    unreadMessage = 2;
}, {
    eventBadge = 1;
    eventId = "-KWWc99ex8f7ksq8TR2U";
    lastMessage = uyfgduihgvifudhviufhvdf;
    timestamp = 5;
    unreadMessage = 1;
}, {
    eventBadge = 1;
    eventId = "-KWE5OYRZnZ5-p3LUotL";
    lastMessage = uyfgduihgvifudhviufhvdf;
    timestamp = 10;
    unreadMessage = 2;
}]
```

I try to use NSSDescriptor :

```
var descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true)
chatsArray.sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])
```

and also to use a typed array (after using a new class)

```
mutableChatsArray.sortInPlace{ ($0.compare($1.timestamp) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending)}
```

So far without success...
Thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you use Swift arrays and dictionaries? It's easier and safer and keeps type information.

Comment: what do you mean by swift arrays and dictionaries (Im relatively new at Swift and I thought that NSMutableArray/Dictionary are also swift related..) If you have any suggestion , Ill be glad to hear it ..

Comment: Read the Swift manual, it's explained. Swift has arrays and dictionaries, no need to use NSArray and NSDictionary which both come from Foundation (they're usable in Swift but they're not Swift). NSArray and NSDictionary were needed in Objective-C because there was no choice, C arrays are terrible - it's not true with Swift anymore.

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3** example

```
  let chatsArray = [[
        "eventBadge" : 1,
        "eventId" : "-KWE39B6Dh7rDzaF-xy4",
        "lastMessage" : "uyfgduihgvifudhviufhvdf",
        "timestamp" : 20,
        "unreadMessage" : 2,
        ], [
            "eventBadge" : 1,
            "eventId" : "-KWWc99ex8f7ksq8TR2U",
            "lastMessage" : "uyfgduihgvifudhviufhvdf",
            "timestamp" : 5,
            "unreadMessage" : 1,
        ], [
            "eventBadge" : 1,
            "eventId" : "-KWE5OYRZnZ5-p3LUotL",
            "lastMessage" : "uyfgduihgvifudhviufhvdf",
            "timestamp" : 10,
            "unreadMessage" : 2,
    ]] as [[String:Any]]

    // to get the timestamp value and store it inside an array with order
    let arrayTimeStamp = (chatsArray.flatMap{$0["timestamp"]} as! Array<Int>).sorted(by: >)
    print(arrayTimeStamp) // [20, 10, 5]

    //to order an array of dictionaries

    let TimeStamp = chatsArray.sorted{$0["timestamp"] as! Int > $1["timestamp"] as! Int }

    print(TimeStamp)

//[["eventId": "-KWE39B6Dh7rDzaF-xy4", "lastMessage":"uyfgduihgvifudhviufhvdf", "timestamp": 20, "unreadMessage": 2, "eventBadge": 1],
//["eventId": "-KWE5OYRZnZ5-p3LUotL", "lastMessage": "uyfgduihgvifudhviufhvdf", "timestamp": 10, "unreadMessage": 2, "eventBadge": 1],
//["eventId": "-KWWc99ex8f7ksq8TR2U", "lastMessage": "uyfgduihgvifudhviufhvdf", "timestamp": 5, "unreadMessage": 1, "eventBadge": 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with NSUserDefaults can be very annoying. I usually follow this technique when getting and setting data from the defaults.

`var mutableArray = defaults.objectForKey("Your Array") as? NSMutableArray
    mutableArray.sortInPlace { (a, b) -> Bool in
    a.start!.compare(b.start!) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    }
    defaults.setValue(mutableArray forKey: "Your Array")`

Answer (score 1):

@Rob and @Fallah , thanks for your answers , Im gonna check them, for now I solve my issue by using the NNSSDescriptor and add it a selector:

```
let descriptor: NSSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:)))
            let sortedChatsArray = (chatsArray as NSArray).sortedArrayUsingDescriptors([descriptor])
```